# How to run a WinSCP from ps1 file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, winscp, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .ps1 file with my script. 
In this script I have a line with:

```
Start-Process "C:\activatebatch.bat"
```

If i execute it directly with ps1 file, everything works well.  But if I set up a Windows Scheduler with ps1 as executive, the bat file doesn't start. In that bat file I have a WinSCP which sends file to server.

How could I set it to start .bat from .ps1 stored in Windows Scheduler? Or how could I execute WinSCP directly from PowerShell code?

I need it to call for WinSCP to send a file into server - and the options are stored in batch file:

```batch
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" user:password@IPI.PIP.IP.IP /command ^
    "put C:\ss\file.txt /home/scripts/windows/" ^
    "exit"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a working WinSCP command line in a batch file, you may need to do few changes to make it compatible with PowerShell:

- Batch file use `^` (caret) to escape a new line. PowerShell uses `` ` `` (backtick). So replace your carets to backticks.
- And you obviously need to escape any characters with a special meaning in PowerShell, particularly `$` (dollar sign), `` ` `` (backtick) and [inner double quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax).

In your simple script, only the first point matters, so the correct command is:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" user:password@IPI.PIP.IP.IP /command `
    "put C:\ss\file.txt /home/scripts/windows/" `
    "exit"
```

---

Though I'd further recommend you using [`winscp.com` instead of `winscp.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) and adding [`/log` switch to enable session logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) for debugging purposes.

Also opening a session using a command-line argument is deprecated. You should use [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) (and better also specify a protocol prefix – `sftp://`?).

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /command `
    "open user:password@IPI.PIP.IP.IP" `
    "put C:\ss\file.txt /home/scripts/windows/" `
    "exit"
```

---

WinSCP 5.14 beta can actually [generate a PowerShell – WinSCP command template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

---

Though for a better control, it's recommended to use [WinSCP .NET assembly from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).