# Not able to trigger .Bat file from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, selenium-grid

I have my BAT file which comprises of steps for setting up Selenium hub in my machine. Below are the commands in Jar files.

```bat
SET HUBHOST=192.168.2.104
IF NOT [%1] == [] SET HUBHOST=%1
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role hub -hubConfig HubConfig.json
Exit
```

I am using powershell to trigger this .bat file.

I have used this command

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Automation\CICDBatFiles\hub.BAT
```

But the .bat file is not triggered. Can any once help me where am I making mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a WinSCP from ps1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852119/how-to-run-a-winscp-from-ps1-file)

Comment: Use cmd.exe and the batch file as an argument.

Comment: why do you trigger that from powershell instead of running directly from powershell?

Comment: I strongly recommend to change the second command line in the batch file to `IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET "HUBHOST=%~1"` to work even on first argument passed to the batch file with surrounding `"`.